# jQuery DateTimePicker Convert date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, datetimepicker

Currently i'm playing around with some jQuery and don't really seems like it works like I would like to.

I got the following code, and I would like it to convert the from to a new date format. It's currently in dd/mm/yyyy and would like it to be yyyy-mm-dd, so I can use it in my mysql database

```
$("#calendarAddEvent").on("click", function() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var from = $("#date").val(); 
    var f = $.datepicker.parseDate("d/m/Y", from);
    var start = $("#time_start").val();
    var end = $("#time_end").val();
    var className = $("#color .selected").attr("data-tag");
    $.post("api/calendar_add.php", {
        title: title, 
        start: f + start,
        end: f + end,
        className: className
    }).done(function() {
        $("#close").click();
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried the moment.js library? It works really well anytime you want to do some date manipulation.

Comment: New to javascript, so don't really know how to do it with moment.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    $("#calendarAddEvent").on("click", function() {
    var name = $("#name").val();

    var from = $("#date").val(); 
    var datestr=(from.split(" ")[0]).split("/");
    f =  new Date(datestr[2],datestr[0]-1,datestr[1]);
    var start = $("#time_start").val();
    var end = $("#time_end").val();
    var className = $("#color .selected").attr("data-tag");
    $.post("api/calendar_add.php", {
        title: title, 
        start: f + start,
        end: f + end,
        className: className
    }).done(function() {
        $("#close").click();
    });
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parseDate' of undefined

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var f = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", from);
```

More docs on datepicker here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: t.getFullYear is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

http://jsfiddle.net/cLLk3a07/1/

```
 $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
$(".calendarAddEvent").click(function(){
var from= $( "#datepicker" ).val();
  console.log(from)
    var date =  $.datepicker.parseDate("mm/dd/yy", from);
    var month = date.getMonth().toString().length == 1 ? "0"+date.getMonth() : date.getMonth();
    var day = date.getDate().toString().length == 1 ? "0"+date.getDate() : date.getDate();
    console.log(date.getFullYear()+"-"+month+"-"+day)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Real problem here is that the second parameter is a string instead of date. You need to convert the string first.

If `#date` is a datepicker you can use this:

```
var from = $("#date").datepicker('getDate').getTime(); 
var f = $.datepicker.parseDate("d/m/Y", new Date(from));
```